# Flatten list containing ints and list of ints

Tags: python

How would you flatten the list `l`:

```
  l = [1,2,[3,4,5],6,7]
```

giving the list:

```
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

This is not the same as flattening:

```
  l = [[1],[2],[3,4,5],[6],[7]]
```

as addressed here:

[How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

where `l` in this case contains only a list of lists of int.

Comment: @Barmar I dont think this is a duplicate of the question you link to as that list doesnt  pertain to a list of mixed types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to solve this problem, which will work with any iterator:

```
l = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6, 7, (8, 9, 10), set([11, 12]), 13, 14]

def flat(l):
    if not l:
        return l
    f = l[0]
    try:
        p = [i for i in f]
    except TypeError:
        # f is not iterable, so put it in a list.
        p = [f]
    return p + flat(l[1:])

print(flat(l))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Any way of testing if container type versus value type while iterating. For example if the list contained: [1,2,3.5, (4.5,5),[6,7,8],set(9,10)]. This should be flattened to: [1,2,3.5,4.5,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: @Baz Check the additional code I added in the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1,2,[3,4,5],6,7] result =[] 

result = []

def flatten(lst):   
  for item in lst:
    if isinstance(item,list):
      flatten(item)
    else:
      result.append(item)

flatten(l)

print(result)
```

Comment: Why is `result` a global variable?